# Access action's out parameter

Tags: c#, action, out

Assuming that for whatever weird reason (interop infact) I have this method

```
void DoSomething(out MyStruct myStruct)
{
    // Setting the struct members here.
}
```

that I want to pass to another method that looks like this:

```
ExecuteAndProcess(Action action)
{
    action();
    // How can I access the out parameter here?
}
```

The problem is that **I don't know how to access the `out` parameter** then; I tried to change the definition of `ExecuteAndProcess` to

```
ExecuteAndProcess(Action action, ref MyStruct myStructParam) 
{ 
    action();
    var member = myStructParam.Property1;
    // ...
}
```

so that I could call it like this in the hope that the `myStructParam` parameter would reflect the changes on the `myStruct` variables

```
MyStruct myStruct = default;
ExecuteAndProcess(() => DoSomething(out myStruct), ref myStructParam);
```

but it doesn't.

---

Is there any way I can **execute the action and access the `out` parameter in the `ExecuteAndProcess` method?**

I sadly cannot make the `DoSomething` simply return the structure instead of passing it as an `out` parameter, because it's implementation is in unmanaged code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with the `Action` type specifically, because there is no `Action` type that includes `out` parameters. But you can create your own delegate type and use that instead:

```
void Main()
{
    ExecuteAndProcess(DoSomething);
}

void ExecuteAndProcess(MyAction action)
{
    MyStruct myStruct;
    action(out myStruct);
    // access the out parameter here
    Console.WriteLine(myStruct.A);
}

delegate void MyAction(out MyStruct myStruct);

void DoSomething(out MyStruct myStruct)
{
    // Setting the struct members here.
    myStruct = new MyStruct{A = 1};
}

public struct MyStruct{
    public int A{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for.